# Initialize A UISegment Control

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I want to initialize my uisegement control to the second option. So when a button is clicked I want to set the uisegement control control to option 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1; // 2nd item
}
```